# Error: Attempting to Install the pgAdmin 4 Web Interface on CentOS 7

Tags: python, pgadmin

```
[root@pgdb-0 pgadmin]# python /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py
NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.

Enter the email address and password to use for the initial pgAdmin user account:

Email address: admin@example.com
```

Results in an Error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/migrations/versions/fdc58d9bd449_.py", line 43, in upgrade
email, password = user_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/setup/user_info.py", line 51, in user_info
email = input("Email address: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
admin@example.com
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

if I encase the email address in single or double quotes, then I get another error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/connection.py", line 38, in <module>
from pgadmin.utils import csv
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/utils/csv.py", line 651, in <module>
register_dialect("excel", excel)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/pgadmin/utils/csv.py", line 486, in register_dialect
raise TypeError('"name" must be a string')
TypeError: "name" must be a string

[root@pgdb-0 pgadmin]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: You are running a  Python 3 module in Python 2. That's not going to work. Try using `python3 …`.

Answer (score 0):

```
python --version
```

if it `2.7` need do this (change version if you have over from `3.5` to you)

---

Start by registering python2 as an alternative

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 50
```

Register python3.5 as an alternative

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 60
```

Select the python to use

```
alternatives --config python
```

---

```
python --version
```

check if you have 3 all good my result:

==============================

```
    [root@localhost ~]# alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 50
    [root@localhost ~]# alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 60
    [root@localhost ~]# alternatives --config python

There are 2 programs which provide 'python'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /usr/bin/python2
*+ 2           /usr/bin/python3.6

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2
[root@localhost ~]# python --version
Python 3.6.8
[root@localhost ~]# python /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/setup.py
NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.

Enter the email address and password to use for the initial pgAdmin user account:

Email address: ****@mail.ru
Password:
Retype password:
pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
======================================

[root@localhost ~]#
```